# How do i redirect all site request with language?

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, web

I am building a website with two language, english and french.
If anyone request http://www.abc.com then i would like to redirect it to http://abc.com/fr and fr is my default language.

anypage request without language en/ or fr/ should redirect to fr/. How do i write htaccess for it

Answer (score 0):

**Redirect www to /fr**

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.abc\.com$ [NC] 
RewriteRule .? http://abc.com/fr%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

**Redirect to /fr if no /en is set**

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/en [NC] 
RewriteRule .? http://abc.com/fr%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

**REQUEST_URI**: The resource requested in the HTTP request line (e.g. "/index.html").

Here is more information about [RewriteCond](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#RewriteCond).